# Android Studio canary must need for try to Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to try to use Jetpack Compose.
I using Android Studio stable version.
A new version of it came a few days ago that version 4.2, then I tried to use Jetpack Compose but it is not able to select `Compose Activity`.

Do I must install Android Studio Canary to attempt Jetpack Compose at this moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct: here is the link to Arctic Fox: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

And here are the instructions for using Compose: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup